# ¡como puedo poner una ventana de video en la ventana principal de tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, video

hola buenas quisiera que me puedan ayudar soy nuevo en esto del lenguaje python me pueden ayudar necesito que la ventana q sale en el cv2.imshow se muestre dentro de la ventana principal del tkinter desde ya muchas gracias

este es el codigo q utilizo pero en este la camara se activa mediante un boton y se abre otra ventana lo que necesito es q dicha ventana este en la misma ventana del tkinter

```
#importamos libreria
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import cv2
import numpy as np
#capturamos video
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#definimos programa "Camara"
def camara():
    while(1):
        _,frame=cap.read()
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
        cv2.imshow('camara',frame)
        k = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
        if k == 27:
            break
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
#cremos ventana principal
ventana=Tk()
ventana.geometry('1000x680+100+100')
ventana.title('Deteccion de mangos')
ventana.config(background='CadetBlue1')
ventana.resizable(width=False, height=False)
#creamos etiquetas
Label(text='Bienvenidos a nuestra aplicacion selectora de mangos',fg='blue',background='orange',font=('Agency FB',25)).place(x=220,y=0)
Label(text='Puertos:',fg='blue',background='orange',font=('Agency FB',14)).place(x=10,y=60)
Label(text='Camara:',fg='blue',background='orange',font=('Agency FB',14)).place(x=10,y=240)
Label(text='Peso',fg='blue',background='orange',font=('Agency FB',14)).place(x=10,y=595)
Label(text='Color',fg='blue',background='orange',font=('Agency FB',14)).place(x=200,y=595)
Label(text='Exportacion',fg='blue',background='orange',font=('Agency FB',14)).place(x=600,y=500)
Label(text='Local',fg='blue',background='orange',font=('Agency FB',14)).place(x=800,y=500)
Label(text='Caracteristicas del mango:',fg='blue',background='orange',font=('Agency FB',14)).place(x=10,y=560)
Label(text='Seleccion de umbral:',fg='blue',background='orange',font=('Agency FB',14)).place(x=10,y=360)
#creamos los botones 
btnBuscar=Button(ventana,text='Buscar',font=('Agency FB',14),width=10,fg='blue',background='yellow').place(x=200,y=60)
btnSave=Button(ventana,text='Save',font=('Agency FB',14),width=10,fg='blue',background='yellow').place(x=10,y=470)
btnOpen=Button(ventana,text='Open',font=('Agency FB',14),width=10,fg='blue',background='yellow').place(x=200,y=470)
btnCamara=Button(ventana,text='Camara',command=camara,font=('Agency FB',14),width=10,fg='blue',background='yellow').place(x=800,y=420)
#creamos el slider del umbral
Umbral=Scale(ventana,label='UMBRAL',orient=HORIZONTAL,from_=0,to=255,length=250).place(x=10,y=400)
#creamos los cuadros de textos
textPeso = ttk.Entry(ventana, state='eadonly').place(x=10,y=640)
textColor = ttk.Entry(ventana, state='readonly').place(x=200,y=640)
#creamos los radiobutton
Radiobutton(ventana, text='Camara Integrada').place(x=10,y=280)
Radiobutton(ventana, text='Camara Usb').place(x=10,y=310)
Radiobutton(ventana, text='Puerto 1').place(x=10,y=100)
Radiobutton(ventana, text='Puerto 2').place(x=10,y=130)
Radiobutton(ventana, text='Puerto 3').place(x=10,y=160)
Radiobutton(ventana, text='Puerto 4').place(x=10,y=190)
#cerramos ciclo de la ventana principal
ventana.mainloop()

introducir el código aquí
```

Comment: Bienvenido Jorge... Que has intentado?? Sería bueno que nos muestres tu código para partir desde ahí... Mientras tanto date una vuelta por [ask] y así ver si puedes mejorar la pregunta

Comment: Hola Jorge, bienvenido a [es.so]. Te recomiendo pasarte por [tour] y [ask] para conocer por encima como funciona el sitio y cómo realizar buenas preguntas. Se entiende que tu problema es embeber video (¿posiblemente la webcam?)  generado por OpenCv en Tkinter. Esto es posible, no embebiendo como tal, sino leyendo frame a frame y mostrándolo en Tkinter. No es demasiado complicado, pero debes mejorar tu pregunta, agregando (usa el botón `editar` que hay debajo de la pregunta) el código que tengas (aunque no sepas como unirlo) para poder ayudarte en base a un trabajo ya hecho. Un saludo.

Comment: hola acabo de subir mi codigo espero me puedan ayudar desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes transformar la imagen que te proporciona cv2 en tkinter PhotoImage. Después situarla en un frame o label de tkinter. Posteo un ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import Tkinter 
import Image, ImageTk


img = cv2.imread('img.png')

b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
img = cv2.merge((r,g,b))

root = Tkinter.Tk()  

# Creamos el objeto Tk PhotoImage a partir de la imagen obtenida de cv2
im = Image.fromarray(img)
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im) 

Tkinter.Label(root, image=imgtk).pack() 

root.mainloop()
```